# Algorithm to compute the largest submodule of two given modules, containing a common submodule

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $M_2\supset N\subset M_1$ be finitely generated modules, say over a polynomial ring. Here the inclusion just means an injection.

There exists a maximal $K$ extending $N$, contained in both $M_1$ and $M_2$. Existence follows from Noetherianity. So we have $N\subset K\subset M_i$ for $i=1,2$, and this $K$ cannot be embedded into a strictly larger common submodule of $M_1,M_2$.

Is there an algorithmic way to find $K$? So starting from presentations of $N,M_1,M_2$, we would find a presentation of $K$?

Edit: I guess it makes more sense to replace $M_1,M_2$ by $M_1/N,M_2/N$ and ask for the largest submodule contained in both, but the question remains the same.

Comment: Unless $M_1$ and $M_2$ are submodules of a common module and you mean that $K=M_1\cap M_2$, which I don’t think is what you do mean, I don’t understand what you mean by “largest”. For example, suppose $N=0$ and each of $M_1$ and $M_2$ is isomorphic to a submodule of the other, then what do you mean by a “largest” $K$ that is contained in both $M_1$ and $M_2$?

Comment: @JeremyRickard Largest was not a good word. I mean maximal. So a submodule $N\hookrightarrow M_1,M_2$, for which there is no $N\hookrightarrow P\hookrightarrow M_1,M_2$,where the composition equals the given maps from $N$ into $M_1,M_2$, and $N\hookrightarrow P$ is a strict inclusion. In your example this would produce either $M_1=M_1\hookrightarrow M_2$, or the other inclusion.

Comment: And there could be other solutions as well. Do you just want to be able to find one possible $K$? I don't know much about algorithms for this kind of thing (or any other kind of thing, for that matter), but this generalizes to the problem, given a module $W$ and submodules $X,Y,Z\leq W$, of finding a submodule $X'\leq W$ maximal subject to $X\leq X'$, $X'\cap Y=0=X'\cap Z$ (take $W=M_1\oplus M_2$, $X=\{(n,n)\mid n\in N\}$, $Y=M_1\oplus0$, $Z=0\oplus M_2$), which maybe could be closer to the kind of problem that's been considered before?

Comment: @JeremyRickard Yes I just want to find one possible $K$. The point is, that I know that in the specific situation I am dealing with, I know there will be a unique largest $K$. However, I do not think that my specific situation is any more suitable for concrete calculations then the general setup in my question, hence why I ask the question in this generality.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Thank you for the suggestion, I will think about this and look around a bit more!